# Pymongo, select random sequences?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, lstm

I have a mongo db collection like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e2d4b6479799acab037af68"), 
  "timestamp" : 1577152302, #hourliy
  "login" : 'A4FC9',
  # 240 columns more
}
```

I want to select random sequences from mongo db with 24 previous reords.

The db doesn`t have records for each hour, sometimes they are mised so I can't make a random timestamp and search the 24 previous records between timestamp ranges.

Currently I'm doing this but it´s really slow and I want to improve performance

```
db = mongodb...

def sequence( size ):
     # first I search for a random row in my db and fetch the timestamb
     random = next( db.aggregate( [{ '$sample': { 'size'  : 1 }}] )['timestamp']

     #then a search the 24 previous
     next_rows = db.find( {'timestamp': {'$lte': random }} ).sort("timestamp",-1).limit( size )
     return next_rows

SEQUENCES = 100

batch = list()
for x in range( SEQUENCES ):
    rand_sequence = sequence( 24 )
    batch.append( rand_sequence )
```

This returns 100 sequences that start from a random timestamp with 24 previous records.
**It takes 30min to fetch all the data**
Is there a way to make this whith just one query?

Also if there is some other way please sugest.

Comment: If each of your queries takes 20 seconds to run (30 minutes for 100 queries) I would either look at why the queries take that long or, perhaps, retrieve the entire data set in one query and then extract data from it in your application.

Comment: The problem is that the collection has almoust 5million (this is way it takes so long i thing) records, and I tried to retrieve all... And the hole Operating System stops working

Comment: Use projections to retrieve the data you need only, and ensure you have adequate memory for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this!!

```
from random import randrange

db = mongodb...

random = next( db.aggregate( [{ '$sample': { 'size'  : 1 }}] )['timestamp']

#then a search the 50000 previous

maxrows = 50000
SEQUENCES = 100
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 100

next_rows = db.find( {'timestamp': {'$lte': random }} ).sort("timestamp",-1).limit(maxrows)

# this makes an array of random indexes to select from
chosed = [ randrange( 0, maxrows - SEQUENCE_LENGTH  ) for x in range( SEQUENCE_LENGTH ) ]

#then i create a list to store all the sequences
sequences_list = [ [] for x in range( len(chosed) ) ]

# then i append all the values in squences_list if the index is previous to SEQUENCE_LENGTH 
for i, x in enumerate( next_rows ):
    for j, y in enumerate(chosed):
        if y >= i and y - SEQUENCE_LENGTH < i:
            #append the values correponding to j position on the list
            sequences_list[j].append( x )
```